# Debugging ESP8266 and Arduino Uno by printing to the Serial Monitor

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-uno, arduino-esp8266

I have a little project that includes connecting EPS8266 to the internet and send an API POST request from the data that is passed from my Arduino Uno. Until now, both module works perfectly fine separately (ESP8266 has succeeded connecting to WiFi and Arduino Uno can get the data from somewhere). Now the problem is how will Arduino Uno send the data to ESP8266 so that ESP8266 can make an API POST request as I mention above to send the data. I'm using UNO+WiFi R3 ATmega328P+ESP8266, 32Mb flash, USB-TTL CH340G, Micro-USB chip and by following this [tutorial](https://robotdyn.com/uno-wifi-r3-atmega328p-esp8266-32mb-flash-usb-ttl-ch340g-micro-usb.html), I know that I have to enable dips number 1 and 2. But by doing so, I will not get the printout that I purposely tell it to (for debugging purpose). I have also watched an Indonesian [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJnLN3n_Pg8&list=WL&index=7&t=174s) that shows me how to upload the code for both modules (but not for debugging purpose), but I noticed it has more actions than the tutorial gave me, I will just post the actions below:
[image: Second dips schemas]

Translations(I know it's self-explaining, but just in case): Koneksi = connection, Komunikasi = communication

From the image above, I saw that there is a way to debug EPS8266 and Arduino Uno's communication, which is enabling dips number 1, 2, 3, and 4. But when I tried it, the data was not sent, which makes me wondering if the trouble lies on the communication between EPS8266 and Arduino Uno, or enabled dips number is wrong for getting the printout. Is there any way of debugging whether my sent data has been received properly?(This is more important since I need to make sure that my data is the correct data) Or is there a way to just debugging whether the communication succeeds?

My code is really simple, just using `Serial.write(something)` on my Arduino Uno and `Serial.get()` on my EPS8266 and both written on my `loop()` method, not `setup()`. I also used 9600 baud rates on my Arduino Uno and 115200 baud rates on my ESP8266 (I of course have also tried changing the baud rates to check if there was a printout).

Answer (score 0):

After uploading to your sketch to ESP8266 by switching ON dips 5,6 & 7

Just flip the dip number 7 to OFF.

Open your "Serial Monitor" in Arduino IDE,

Select the correct baud rate, then press the reset button on your Arduino.

You will be able to see your debug messages in your Arduino IDE "Serial Monitor".

Hope this helps.